# Single 1 pixel diagonal line background

Tags: website-design

i try to add a diagonal line in the background of a div. i wonder if it's possible to do it without to use a .png image. I saw some css options but the render quality is poor and the line don't touch both side.

[image: diagonal line]

Comment: If you're asking for help with implementation, please include what you've tried and why it didn't work with screenshots. Please edit your post with what your desired results are, what resources you referenced and why those didn't work. See [this meta post](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/699/request-new-close-reason-what-have-you-tried) for discussion and see [this post](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a good question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems to be more of a stackoverflow question -- or in very very least not a graphic design related question.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're talking about styling a DIV and tried a CSS solution (and there is actually a good and working one), this question would be better asked on StackOverflow. 
But since I know how to use CSS I'll answer here now anyway.

Create two DIVs. One for the red box, one for the white line like so

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="line"></div>
</div>
```

Then add the CSS

```
.container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: red;
}

.line {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  left: -50%;
  width: 300%;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
      -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg); /* IE 9 */
          transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

The result will look like [this working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jascha/jweksxrr/1/).

[image]

Comment: This solution will only work if the container's height and width are the same (You could do it with other dimensions, but you'd have to break out some trig to calculate the correct angle)

Comment: Same goes for any other solution presented here,  they all  use deg to set the angle of the line. But this is the only solution that renders as a perfect  1px line. I assumed the OP wants a square DIV.

Answer (score 2):

If you can live without it being exactly 1px, you can use pure CSS on a single div by using a background gradient:

[image]

```
div {
   width: 400px;
   height: 400px;
   background: linear-gradient(135deg, #ff3232 0%,#ff3030 49.6%,#d6d6d6 50%,#ff3030 50.4%,#ff0000 100%);
}
```

The catch is that you set gradients by % so you likely will never get exactly a 1px line in the center. But it's lean markup.

[JSBin Example](https://jsbin.com/zowuloxoqa/edit?html,css,output)

Comment: Downvoter? Suggestions?

Comment: True. In addtion, I would recommend to have 'to bottom right' instead of degrees as degrees in not responsive in case if it has to be exact diagonal

Answer (score 2):

I don't have the rep to comment on 'DA01's answer, but the 'fuzzy' edge can be eliminated by setting the size of the background to match the size of the div and setting those coordinates to be in px as opposed to %:

```
background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, #f00 0, #f00 281px, #ddd 282px, #f00 283px, #f00 566px);
background-size: 400px, 400px;
```

The downside to this approach is that you need to have the dimensions of the div and background fixed or change it through javascript on-the-fly.

Comment: ooh! Good point! If it's a known size for the div, this is perfect!